# PHP Regex get UPPERCASE Name

Tags: php, regex, unicode, uppercase

I have these names:

```
John Stuart AGNEW
Magdi Cristiano ALLAM
Josefa AÉNDRÉS BARÉA 
Josefa ANDRES BAREA
Laima Liucija ANDRIKIENĖ
```

and I want to get name that have all UPPERCASE chars

For example, for `John Stuart AGNEW` I want to get **AGNEW**

I faced problem with `Josefa AÉNDRÉS BARÉA`. I want to get **AÉNDRÉS BARÉA**

I used this regex: `(.*) (.[A-Z]{2,100} .[A-Z]{2,100})`

Could someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) `\p{Lu}` should match any upper case letter. So replacing your regular expression to something like so: `(.*) (.\p{Lu}{2,100} .\p{Lu}{2,100})` should work.

I did some modification which should make your regular expression slightly more tolerant. `(\p{Lu}{2,100}( \p{Lu}{2,100})?)`. I however have no experience with PHP so I am unable to test it properly.

I have however, tested it on a Java environment and it worked for me.

Comment: @mgraph regexr is not good for testing PHP regexes, the Javascript regex engine and PHP's PCRE engine differ heavily, Javascript does not support a lot of things that PHP does. Try it in PHP.

Comment: can you try this? http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/index.php it's for php specifically - I was trying this regex `#\b\p{Lu}+\b#` and it keeps splitting the AÉNDRÉS to AÉNDR and ÉS which is just ridiculous - do you know why ?

Comment: @EvanMulawski: At the moment I am trying to get it to work, but that is the same regular expression posted by the OP.

Comment: @npinti it's works, but if name have only one word that is UPPERCASE it's not showing, should i add OR |

Comment: i did : `#\b(.*) ((.\p{Lu}{2,100} .\p{Lu}{2,100})|(.\p{Lu}{2,100}))\b#`

Comment: @npinti but if i have (Inès AYALA SENDER) it returns only "SENDER"

Comment: @mgraph: I have updated my answer. In my case, the second group always yielded the upper case surnames.

Comment: @npinti i used `(\p{Lu}{2,100}( \p{Lu}{2,100})?)` same thing return only the last UPPERCASE word of the sentence  (Inès AYALA SENDER)

Comment: @mgraph: The above regular expression should return 2 groups. I apologize for the mistake I made, I meant the first group not the second.

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
([A-ZÁÉÍÓÚÜ]{2,})
```

and then concatenate the matches using:

```
$result = implode(" ", $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it might be what you need

```
<?php

$s = 'John Stuart AGNEW
Magdi Cristiano ALLAM
Josefa AÉNDRÉS BARÉA
Josefa ANDRES BAREA
Laima Liucija ANDRIKIENE
Ronald McDONALD
';

$pat = "/\p{Lu}{2,}.*/";
preg_match_all( $pat, $s, $ms);

foreach( $ms[0] as $m){
    echo $m . "<br />\n";
}

?>
```

Note, some names like McDONALD are mixed cases, are you going to support these too?

Answer (score 0):

Your first `(.*)` should be made non-greedy, like this: `(.*?)`, so that this doesn't start accepting letters from the uppercase part of the name.

And then as others mentioned, you could extend the range `[A-Z]` to `[A-ZÁÉÍÓÚÜ]`